# Intercepting webpi2 calls with Windsor Castle

Tags: asp.net-web-api, castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api2, castle

I'm using webapi2 and Castle Windsor. I'm trying to intercept calls to the ApiController to make some logging, but I can't find in the parameter the method called, url, parameters, etc. The method name returned is ExecuteAsync.

This is my interceptor call (which is hit)

```
    public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var methodName = invocation.Method.Name;
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean `invocation.Arguments`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (invocation.Method.Name == "ExecuteAsync")
{
    var ctx = (HttpControllerContext) invocation.Arguments[0];
    Console.WriteLine("Controller name: {0}", ctx.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName);
    Console.WriteLine("Request Uri: {0}", ctx.Request.RequestUri);
}
invocation.Proceed();
```

Intercepting the ExecuteAsync call, you can get access to the HttpControllerContext but not the HttpActionContext, which contains details about the actual controller action method being invoked. (As far as I can tell this is only available to an ActionFilter).

Therefore the detail about the request is limited: for instance, deserialized parameters are not available using this technique.

If you wish, you can make your controller action methods `virtual` and these will then also be intercepted, and you can then access the actual action parameters via `invocation.arguments`. However, in your interceptor you will need to somehow differentiate the action methods that you wish to log, from the other methods that get called on the controller (i.e. `Intialize()`, `Dispose()`, `ExecuteAsync()`, `Ok()`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

While using ASP.NET MVC framework is possible to get the action caller from LoginInterceptor (check [this link](https://cangencer.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/asp-net-mvc-3-aspect-oriented-programming-with-castle-interceptors/)), in ASP.NET Web Api I haven't found a proper way to achieve it using interceptors with Castle Windsor.

By the other hand, I have found a way to achive what you are trying to do, taking advantage of `Caller Info Attributes` and Castle Windsor `LoggingFacility` component.

**Caller Info Attributes**

These attributes are

- [CallerMemberName] - Sets the information about caller member name.
- [CallerFilePath] - Sets the information about caller's source code
  file.
- [CallerLineNumber] - Sets the information about caller's line number.

And you can use them this way (as optional parameters):

```
public static void ShowCallerInfo([CallerMemberName] 
      string callerName = null, [CallerFilePath] string 
      callerFilePath = null, [CallerLineNumber] int callerLine=-1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caller Name: {0}", callerName);
    Console.WriteLine("Caller FilePath: {0}", callerFilePath);
    Console.WriteLine("Caller Line number: {0}", callerLine);
}
```

Calling `ShowCallerInfo();` method (without parameters) displays:

```
Caller Name: Main
Caller FilePath: h:\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Class1.cs
Caller Line number: 7
```

**LoggingFacility**

Castle Windsor provides the `LoggingFacility` component as an alternative for Logging (using injection instead of interception), that allows logging inside your methods, not only after and before (allowed with interceptors).

Just registering your Logger this way:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseNLog().WithConfig("NLog.config"));
```

Automatically injects an ILogger object that can use in your code.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        Logger.Info("Log Test");
        …
    }
    ...
}
```

Check this [link](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Logging-Facility.ashx) and this [link](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Five-Adding-logging-support.ashx) for more info.

**Example**

So, as an example, you can mix both features to achieve Logging in controller actions this way:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    // Make Logger optional
    private ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;
    public ILogger Logger
    {
        get { return logger; }
        set { logger = value; }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        loggerError("Error");

        ...

        return Ok();
    }

    ....

    public void loggerError(string message, 
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "", 
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
    {
        Logger.Error(message + 
            " - Caller Name: " + memberName 
            + " - Caller FilePath: " + sourceFilePath 
            + " - Line number: " + sourceLineNumber
        );
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using already a the logging facility, but I don't want to polute the classes, that's way I wanted to put it in an Interceptor...Thx anyways!